# Why is this power supply split?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, pcb-design, schematics

I am looking at a [schematic](https://github.com/PX4/Hardware/blob/master/FMUv3_REV_D/Schematic%20Print/Schematic%20Prints.PDF) for the Pixhawk 2 board. It has a complex power distribution system (see photo below)

[image]

Much of the complexity exists for one of two reasons

- redundancy
- shutting off external connections so an external short does not kill the system

The part that interests me is in the bottom right hand corner of the photo labeled "FMU LDO" (U5001 in the schematic). There are separate regulator outputs for the microcontroller (FMU) and the sensors. I am not clear why they split the supply here.

What value does that add? Would this circuit behave correctly on a single supply?

Comment: One possible value in splitting power supplies between digital MCU and analog sensors is to reduce/decouple digital noise from analog circuitry

Comment: @jsotola Sorry, I changed it to "FMU LDO"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using separate LDO's not only decouples logic noise from high SNR sensors it splits the power dissipation to reduce Cu area needed for Heatinsk can be used.

Pd= (300+300)mA *(5-3.3V)=1.02W ~ 10sq cm 2x sided with thermal vias.